# Best method for finding and replacing a subarray

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've written some code to find a desired sub-array within a larger array and replace it with a different sub-array of the same length.
e.g.:

```
int array[] = {1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4};
int find[] = {1,2,3};
int replace[] = {7,8,9};
replaceSubArray(array, 8, find, replace, 3);
```

And replaceSubArray modifies 'array' to contain {7,8,9,4,7,8,9,4}

My function looks like this:

```
void replaceSubArray(char* longArray, int longLength, char* find, char* replace, int shortLength) {

    int findIndex = 0, replaceIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < longLength; ++i)                            //loop through larger array
    {
        if (longArray[i] == find[findIndex])                        //if we find a match for an element
        {
            if (++findIndex == shortLength)                         //increment the findIndex and see if the entire subarray has been found in the larger array
            {
                for (int j = i - (shortLength - 1); j <= i; ++j)    //entire array has been matched so go back to start of the appearance of subarray in larger array
                {
                    longArray[j] = replace[replaceIndex];           //replace the matched subarray with the contents of replace[]
                    replaceIndex++;
                }
                replaceIndex = 0;                                   //reset replaceIndex and findIndex to 0 so we can restart the search for more subarray matches
                findIndex = 0;
            }
        } else {                                                    //if an element wasn't matched, reset findIndex to 0 to restart the search for subarray matches
            findIndex = 0;
        }
        replaceIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

It works fine but I am a beginner programmer and was curious if there is any better way to do this? Or if there are any built in functions that would help.

Comment: Don't dual tag a question like this with C and C++ — the best way to do it in C++ is completely different from the best way to do it in C.  Which are you learning?

Comment: C++ sorry, but I did start with C. The function I've written is valid in both correct?

Comment: The problem is "the best way" — what's best in C++ isn't possible in C.

Comment: This question looks more suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Note that the call to `replaceSubArray()` that you show does not call the function `replaceSubArray()` that you show — passing 3 arguments to a function that expects 5 won't work (unless you're able to provide defaults for the last 2 arguments, but given the prototype, that isn't going to work, and the code doesn't attempt it).

Comment: Substring matching is a (to me) surprisingly complex topic. You might like to look into the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm). This has been part of the C++ standard library since C++17, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/boyer_moore_searcher)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes I'm aware I left out the sizes, that was just to explicitly describe what I was trying to achieve. And thanks for pointing out the boyer-moore algorithm it seems pretty cool.

Comment: If you're posting code to SO, it should be as nearly correct as you can make it — apart from whatever problem you're having.  That means that function calls to functions shown in the question should be accurate, amongst other things.  You'd do better to fix the faulty code than to protest that you know it is wrong but that's OK because it is a question on SO.  When you have any reputation, you're likely to find such behaviour loses reputation.  As a newcomer, you don't have reputation to lose.

Comment: @user3386109: Are you sure? The `findIndex` goes from 0 to 3 (the length of the string to be found, not the length of the string to be searched). And `i` is monotonically increasing. I think the code is vulnerable to the problem I pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57721298/best-subarray#comment101884793_57721582) below — the answer has fixed that bug, but the code in the question, I believe, is vulnerable to it. The fix is simple enough (I think — I haven't tested it): after the replacing loop, set `i = j - 1;`, which requires `int j;` before the loop, not in it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're right. I misunderstood the usage of the `findIndex`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use standard algorithms.  You have

```
int array[] = {1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4};
int find[] = {1,2,3};
int replace[] = {7,8,9};
```

then you can use (requires `#include <algorithm>`, `#include <iterator>`)

```
using std::begin, std::end;

auto it = begin(array);
for (;;) {
    it = std::search(it, end(array), begin(find), end(find));
    if (it == end(array))
        break;
    it = std::copy(begin(replace), end(replace), it);
}
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rdVSs9FvRBH6VhkL))

---

You can also use the Boyer-Moore searcher: (requires `#include <functional>`)

```
using std::begin, std::end;

auto searcher = std::boyer_moore_searcher(begin(find), end(find));
auto it = begin(array);
for (;;) {
    it = std::search(it, end(array), searcher);
    if (it == end(array))
        break;
    it = std::copy(begin(replace), end(replace), it);
}
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pzv61BDsGkDoVj6g))

Whether or not this will improve performance depends on a lot of factors, so profile.

Comment: I hate to rain on your parade, but … if you change the code to use `int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 };` and `int replace[] = { 3, 1, 2 };`, then the result is `{ 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2 }`, which probably isn't the expected result.  The problem is that the search resumes at one after the last start of a found string, not after the end of the replacement string.  I don't know if there's an easy way around that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Bug indeed, fixed.

Comment: Seems that the boyer-moore algorithm is regarded as the best algorithm for searching like this. Thanks for showing me how to use it here. I think I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**To replace just the first occurence:**

```
#include <string.h>

void replaceSubArray(int* longArray, int longLength, int* find, int* replace, int shortLength)
{
    int i, k = 0;
    for (i = 0 ; i < longLength ; ++i)
    {
        if (longArray[i] == find[k++])
        {
            if ( k == shortLength )
            {
                memcpy(longArray + i + 1 - k, replace, sizeof(int) * shortLength);
                break;
            }

            continue;
        }

        k = 0;
    }
}
```

**To replace all occurences:**

```
#include <string.h>

void replaceSubArray(int* longArray, int longLength, int* find, int* replace, int shortLength)
{
    int i, k = 0;
    for (i = 0 ; i < longLength ; ++i)
    {
        if (longArray[i] == find[k++])
        {
            if ( k == shortLength )
                memcpy(longArray + i + 1 - k, replace, sizeof(int) * shortLength);
            else
                continue;
        }
        k = 0;
    }
}
```

In `C` I would prefer this way.

PS: The question was tagged with `C` too before. Noticed that just now that `C` tag has been removed. Still posted in case if it helps.

Comment: Does this replace each occurrence, as shown in the example data, or just the first occurrence?

Answer (score 1):

If the elements in your find-array are all different, you could in most cases skip some indexes in your else-case:

replace:

```
else {                                                    //if an element wasn't matched, reset findIndex to 0 to restart the search for subarray matches
        findIndex = 0;
     }
```

with

```
else {                             //if an element wasn't matched, reset findIndex to 0 to restart the search for subarray matches
        findIndex = 0;
        i+=find.length-findIndex;  // there could not be a match starting before this index.
     }
```

If not all entries in your find-index are different you could use a similar (more complicated) approach. See [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)

---

Using `memcpy` instead of a loop to make the actual replace should also speed things up a bit.

---

**Hint:**

**Always** profile each change to see if, and in which extend, the change improved the performance.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the sample code  in which I used std::vector and  few already present feature of c++

```
#include<stdio.h>                                                               
#include<iostream>                                                              
#include<vector>                                                                
#include<algorithm>                                                             

int main () {                                                                   


    std::vector<int> vect1 = {1,2,3,4,5};                                       
    std::vector<int> find = {3,4,5};                                            
    std::vector<int> replace = {5,6,7};                                         

    auto it = std::search(vect1.begin(),vect1.end(),find.begin(),find.end());    // Finds sub array in main vect1

    int i = 0;                                                                  
    while ((it != vect1.end()) && (i< replace.size())) {                                                 
        *it = replace[i];   // replace each elements on by one start from searched index from std::search                      
        i++;                        //iterate replace vector                                            
        it++;                       //iterate main vector                                            
    }                                                                           

    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

Comment: your `std::replace` line isn't doing the right thing

Comment: why do you think so?

Comment: after the start of the matching pattern it is replacing every instance of `3` with `5`, every `4` with `6`, every `4` with `7`. This works with the example data as there are no repeated numbers but is not the intended behaviour. `std::replace` should simply be `*it = replace[i]` or just use `std::copy` as L.F's answer.

Comment: In fact there are other bugs, your while condition is incorrect if the array to be replaced isn't at the end. Passing `*it` to `std::replace` uses a reference which makes it only replace one character which hides the fact that `std::replace` is not the right function